# Twitter4j Request Token in Session (Struts2 in Google-App-Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, struts2, twitter4j

In my action I stored the request token as follow:

```
//TwitterOath
public String execute(){
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

    try {
        RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(REDIRECT_URI);
        authUrl = requestToken.getAuthenticationURL();

        //session
        Map<String, Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
        session.put("requestToken", requestToken);

    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

In REDIRECT_URI action:

```
RequestToken requestToken = (RequestToken)
    ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get("requestToken");
```

The problem is that sometimes, requestToken is null.

Comment: any clue what those sometime conditions are? I am using the session based token mechanism in many application but have not seen such error/exception.Still you can store token in database if u like

Comment: i also don't have a clue. i'm still looking into this.

Comment: you can always reply on storing the request token in the database

Comment: i understand that I can store it in the database since it will only expire if the user revoke the site, but the REDIRECT_URI page is for the first time authentication of the site.

Comment: i believe you are getting confused in Access_Token and Request_Token as both are used for different purpose

Comment: OMG. Your right @UmeshAwasthi. Which one should I saved in the database? request token or access token? I'm confused on how to track those token to a twitter user.

Comment: `Access_Token` is one which is being given by Oauth provider to access user data, its like a key to user profile.Twitter make it more easy by not setting any expiry for the `Access_Token`.

Comment: is there such thing as START SESSION in Struts2? For what I have observed, the problem was encountered if the session has timed out and development server was restarted.

Comment: no, that i snot possible and more over session is related to server.you can ask server to create new session and even configure not to invalidate/expire session but that i snot a good approach

Comment: I'm having the same issue and this is not only in struts2, it's there in normal JSP too. Sometimes, it's blank. Anyways, twitter4j seems to work in normal JSP app, but not in struts2, I believe the requestToken is not stored properly in struts2-session, I'm looking for a solution since past 2 weeks ago. It used to work fine earlier, but one day it stuck and till date it's stuck. Please share struts2-code if you've solved it.